# Distance from point to two line segments

Tags: python, pygame, line, distance

I'm rather new to coding and am trying to check whether a dot drawn (in pygame)is on the last line drawn (making the sprouts game).

I have two lists, both holding coordinates of the line segments (in 30pix) just drawn, and one with last dot drawn.

```py
current_line = []
dot_pos = []
```

Distance function I found online:

```
def dist_point_to_line(line1, line2, point):
    x0 = point[0]
    y0 = point[1]
    x1 = line1[0]
    y1 = line1[1]
    x2 = line2[0]
    y2 = line2[1]
    px = x2-x1
    py = y2-y1
    norm = px*px + py*py
    u =  ((x0 - x1) * px + (y0 - y1) * py) / float(norm)
    if u > 1:
        u = 1
    elif u < 0:
        u = 0
    x = x1 + u * px
    y = y1 + u * py
    dx = x - x0
    dy = y - y0
    dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    return dist
```

Now I want to implement the check at each segment of the line, but I'm stuck. Any advice?

This is what I thought of, though it doesn't want to work:

```py
def distance_check():
    for i in range(len(current_line)-1):
        if dist_point_to_line(current_line[i], current_line[i+1], dot_pos) < 10:
            return True #dot allowed to be placed
    return False
```

Comment: You're right that was the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If `dot_pos` is a list then you have to get the last element of the list (`dot_pos[-1]`). Note the arguments to the function `dist_point_to_line` are single dots, rather than a list of dots:

```py
def distance_check():
    for i in range(len(current_line)-1):
        if dist_point_to_line(current_line[i], current_line[i+1], dot_pos[-1]) < 10:
            return True #dot allowed to be placed
    return False
```